# How to add a reference to a class library with all references of this library?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dependencies, .net-assembly

I try to explain my issue.

I have my own windows service(**WS**). This **WS** refers on `Helpers.dll`. `Helpers.dll` it's my own *class library* that has several references. One of this references is `System.Web.Mvc.dll`.

For example if I'm adding reference on `Helpers.dll` to my **WS**, all references from `Helpers.dll` won't be added to **WS**.(At most situations this behavior is true, I think)

I'm trying to set `Copy Local = True` inside properties of reference on `Syste.Web.Mvc.dll` (`Helpers.csproj`)

[image]

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Nothing changes, though.

Without references that placed in Helpers.dll my **WS** doesn't work correctly.
`TypeInitializationException` will been thrown in the rintume. (Exception happens inside static constructor that tries to execute `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` method one of this assemblies is `Helpers.dll` with link on `System.Web.Mvc.dll`)

How to add a class library reference with all references of this library?

Exactly, i can to add this references (`System.Web.Mvc.dll`) in **WS** project by hand, I want to do this by settings or `.config` file or somethig else.

Actually, I use code below for dynamic resolving assembly:

Any way, I get the exception inside **WS** after the first using `AssemblyHelpers` class during resolving assemblies - my **WS** uses `Helpers.dll` that uses `System.Web.Mvc.dll`(this `dll` is placed only in *bin* folder of Helpers project and isn't palced in bin foder of **WS**).

But my **WS** also uses a `AssemblyHelpers` class that tries to load `System.Web.Mvc.dll`(first, custom assembly resolver loads `Helpers.dll` and then all references from this `dll`, including `System.Web.Mvc.dll`) and gets a Exception(`Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException`). \

`System.Web.Mvc.dll` isn't in bin folder of my **WS**.

```
public static class AssemblyHelper
{
    private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();

    private static readonly List<Assembly> _assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

    public static ICollection<Assembly> SyncronizedList
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                return new List<Assembly>(_assemblies);
            }
        }
    }

    static AssemblyHelper()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(OnAssemblyLoad);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += new EventHandler(OnDomainUnload);

        // explicitly register previously loaded assemblies since they was not registered yet
        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            RegisterAssembly(assembly);
        }
    }

    private static void OnAssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        if (RegisterAssembly(args.LoadedAssembly))
        {
            ExecuteAllExecuteOnAssemblyLoadMethods(args.LoadedAssembly);
        }
    }

    private static void OnDomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (Assembly assembly in SyncronizedList)
        {
            ExecuteAllExecuteOnDomainUnloadMethods(assembly);
        }
    }

    public static bool RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    {
        if (assembly == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");
        }
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            if (_assemblies.Contains(assembly))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                _assemblies.Add(assembly);
                ExecuteAllExecuteOnAssemblyLoadMethods(assembly);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnAssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        if (RegisterAssembly(args.LoadedAssembly))
        {
            ExecuteAllExecuteOnAssemblyLoadMethods(args.LoadedAssembly);
        }
    }

    private static void OnDomainUnload(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (Assembly assembly in SyncronizedList)
        {
            ExecuteAllExecuteOnDomainUnloadMethods(assembly);
        }
    }

    public static ICollection<MethodInfo> FindAllMethods(Assembly assembly, Type attributeType)
    {
        String assemblyName = "unknown";
        String attributeTypeName = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (assembly == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");
            }
            assemblyName = assembly.FullName;
            if (attributeType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("attributeType");
            }
            attributeTypeName = attributeType.FullName;
            List<MethodInfo> lst = new List<MethodInfo>();
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                foreach (MethodInfo mi in type.GetMethods(
                    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
                {
                    if (Attribute.IsDefined(mi, attributeType))
                    {
                        lst.Add(mi);
                    }
                }
            }
            return lst;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //exception
        }
    }

    public static int ExecuteAllMethods(Assembly assembly, Type attributeType)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (MethodInfo mi in FindAllMethods(assembly, attributeType))
        {
            try
            {
                mi.Invoke(null, null);
                count++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to execute method {0} of {1}, reason: {2}",
                    mi.Name, mi.DeclaringType, Converter.GetExceptionMessageRecursive(ex)));
            }
        }
        return count;
    }


    public static ICollection<MethodInfo> FindAllExecuteOnAssemblyLoadMethods(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return FindAllMethods(assembly, typeof(Attributes.ExecuteOnAssemblyLoadAttribute));
    }

    public static ICollection<MethodInfo> FindAllExecuteOnDomainUnloadMethods(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return FindAllMethods(assembly, typeof(Attributes.ExecuteOnDomainUnloadAttribute));
    }

    public static int ExecuteAllExecuteOnAssemblyLoadMethods(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return ExecuteAllMethods(assembly, typeof(Attributes.ExecuteOnAssemblyLoadAttribute));
    }

    public static int ExecuteAllExecuteOnDomainUnloadMethods(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return ExecuteAllMethods(assembly, typeof(Attributes.ExecuteOnDomainUnloadAttribute));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to add a reference to a class library with all references of this library?

You shouldn't add every transitive dependency you have as a assembly reference. Reference is required to import types from another assembly and make it usable in your code.

I think the real problem is the process of deploying the dependent assemblies to the build folder. Try to use some advice in the question: [MSBuild doesn't pick up references of the referenced project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137229/msbuild-doesnt-pick-up-references-of-the-referenced-project)

The modern way to deal with transitive dependencies (to deploy it correctly to every dependent project) is the using of package manager. NuGet is the de-facto standard for this purpose. Also a lot of innovations in DNX project system are intended to solve such issues and to use NuGet packages as the first-class build and deploy entities.

Comment: Absolutely, Nuget has really helped me

Comment: I agree, you should use NuGet or some other package manager to manage your dependencies like this. If you really must include other assemblies, you could try something like ILMerge http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to thank @Nipheris for the answer and proposal to use Nuget. Using of Nuget really helps me.

Any way, i've been getting the error. I think try to use unity instead custom dependency resolver(`AssemblyHelper` class is part of that) helper. In my opinion, the using of custom dependency resolver has been getting me error.